# How do I get pages marked +1 in Google search results to rise to the top?

Tags: google-search, google-plus-1

I've noticed that pages where I have marked with +1 have "You +1'd this" in Google search results.

However, it doesn't seem to affect the order of results, or there may be very small differences I can't see or notice.

How do I get pages marked +1 on top of other search results?

I was thinking of using it like a "read it later" or similar service. Like when I mark web pages "read it later", but never read them. If +1 marked pages appear on top of search result, it may be the time to read them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this WIRED article](http://www.wired.com/epicenter/2011/08/google-studying-re-ranking-search-results-using-1-button-data-but-its-touchy/), +1 Google is investigating wether to consider it as a signal in future updates of the search engine.

> Google confirmed its plans in an e-mail to Wired.com.
>
> “Google will study the clicks on +1 buttons as a signal that influences the ranking and appearance of websites in search results,” a spokesman wrote. “The purpose of any ranking signal is to improve overall search quality. For +1’s and other social ranking signals, as with any new ranking signal, we’ll be starting carefully and learning how those signals are related to quality.”

So, for now at list, the pages you are +1-ing will not change ranking.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I think Google will give us the "you +1'd" search tool in near feature at least.

Comment: A friend of mine mentioned that [Evernote extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc) does same kind of thing what I want if you clip a page.